# Hide text from user with jQuery in userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

How can i block/hide the user **dbs** all posts? With a userscript?

```
 <article class="container">
  <div class="messages" id="messages">
   <div class="message info">
    <span class="nick">
     <a title="2016-01-27 16:27:48">
      *
     </a>
    </span>
   <pre class="text">Users online: Hej</pre> 
  </div>
  <div class="message info">
   <span class="nick">
    <a title="2016-01-27 16:27:58">
     *
    </a>
   </span>
   <pre class="text">dbs joined</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
   <span class="nick">
    <a title="2016-01-27 16:24:55">
     dbs
    </a>
   </span>
   <pre class="text">Hej</pre>
  </div>
 </div>
</article>
```

I know that if dbs change nick i get the message again..

site is https://hack.chat/?lil and lil is the room..

**EDIT:**

My plan was something like this

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        HackChat
// @namespace   some
// @description Hide unwanted user.
// @include     https://hack.chat/*
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
// @version     1.0
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- waitForKeyElements():  A utility function, for Greasemonkey scripts,
that detects and handles AJAXed content.

Usage example:

    waitForKeyElements (
        "div.comments"
        , commentCallbackFunction
    );

    //--- Page-specific function to do what we want when the node is found.
    function commentCallbackFunction (jNode) {
        jNode.text ("This comment changed by waitForKeyElements().");
    }

IMPORTANT: This function requires your script to have loaded jQuery.
*/
var hiddenNick = $("article.container............").has ("dbs");

hiddenNick.hide ();
```

Comment: No one has a answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

use jquery -> put the stuff you want to hide into a div with an id -> either in document load or some action (eg. mouseover, click etc...) -> call hide(); on the div element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     // Either an action function or on document load...
     $( ".hideMe" ).hide();
</script>

<div id="hideMe">
<!-- Some content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry.. But I think you misunderstood me. Because I asked for an userscript to hide the content..